# Cannot add wintrust.dll

Tags: winapi, pinvoke, digital-signature

Now I'm working on a project automatically check out whether the file is digital signed, using the wintrust.dll. Below is the colde

```
[DllImport("wintrust.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern WinVerifyTrustResult WinVerifyTrust(
    [In] IntPtr hwnd,
    [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid pgActionID,
    [In] WinTrustData pWVTData
);
```

But there is error message about the class WinVerityTrustResult and WinTrustData class that they cannot be found. I tried to add the reference wintrust.dll and had registered it, but it prompt that I can't add the wintrust.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have copied the function declaration from [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wintrust.winverifytrust). You also need to include the user defined types declared further down that page.